How to mock an object created inside a function
I would like to create unit test for my C# application. There are the functions which create objects inside and perform some checks on the created object. Since I want it to be unit test, functions should be separated from the object dependencies. Is there a way to mock objects created inside the function?
In the following code block, DeviceManager class is under unit test and ConnectWirelessDeviceToSystem unit is tested. However, function code block depends the creation of WirelessDevice object which needs to be mocked.


public struct Device
{
    public WirelessDevice WirelessDevice { get; set; }

    public ushort unitId { get; set; }

}

public class WirelessDevice
{
    public bool HasSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public ushort UnitId { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public WirelessDevice(ushort unitId, string serialNumber)
    {
        this.UnitId = unitId;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serialNumber))
        {
            HasSerialNumber = true;
            this.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<uint, Device> _devices = new Dictionary<uint, Device>();
    public async Task ConnectWirelessDeviceToSystem(ushort unitId)
    {
        WirelessDevice wirelessDevice = _devices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == unitId).Value.WirelessDevice;
        if (wirelessDevice == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (wirelessDevice.HasSerialNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device has serial number {0}", wirelessDevice.SerialNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device does not have serial number, can not connect to system");
        }
    }

    public bool Add(ushort unitId, string serialNumber)
    {
        WirelessDevice wirelessDevice = new WirelessDevice(
           unitId,
           serialNumber);

        _devices.Add(unitId, new Device()
        {
            WirelessDevice = wirelessDevice,
            unitId = unitId,
        });

        return true;
    }
}


I have tried using Moq framework but could not achieve mocking object created in the function.

You want to create a mock for _devices or the call chain attach to it. We don't see what that is so can't help.

Your intuition seems correct, but could not achieve mocking doesn't adequately explain what the problem was.

Please edit the post so that it shows the origin of _devices.

@Ralf Want to mock WirelessDevice object which is received _device dictionary

Then get a WirelessDevice (or a mock of that) into the _devices list we don't see how that is or could be filled. If WirelessDevice is a pure data class  (it sound a bit like that) i would not mock it but just use it. You should strive to mock functionality not data.

You added the Device wrapper twice in the sample code. Seeing WirelessDevice and how its added to the Dictionary would be more helpful.

As currently defined, the example always creates an empty _devices dictionary, and thus the ConnectWirelessDeviceToSystem method is always going to return without doing anything. Please edit the question so that it provides minimal, reproducible example.

@MarkSeemann that is not the exact method. I have reduced the code just to understand  how I can mock an object declared and used in the function.

@Ralf WirelessDevice class does not only hold data it also has functions that does some works.

If you're testing ConnectWirelessDeviceToSystem you could call Add with your mock data, add the WirelessDevice, then perform your assertions.

To get something into the Dictionary you have the Add method and unfortunately it uses an explicit new on that class so isn't easily mockable. Then the question is can you simply use an actual WirelessDevice instance created there? Your code looks like so i would just do that. If not and you don't want to change production code to make it testable use Reflection to add a mock to the _devices dictionary directly(ignoring the Add method).

I understand that this is an attempt at a MRE, but the crux of the matter is whether or not you have the option to replace wirelessDevice with a Test Double. Since you pull that object out of _devices, the only chance you have of replacing that with a Test Double is if _devices is externally modifiable. We can't, however, see that from the code currently available to us.
